# Get the combined width of all li items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I made a function to get all the widths of all the `li` items in the navigation menu, but this function (below) puts all the item's widths into an array.

I do not need not an array. I just need one total number that is the sum of all the li's widths.

How can I change the array to one variable?

Thank you.

```
var navigationItemsWidth = $.map($('.navigation-bar .nav li'),function(val){
    return $(val).width();
});
```

Comment: @shijin: Your edit has actually made the question less clear.He was not after the "count of li".

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Okay,sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map is a function that create an array, what you want is adding a value. use `.each`:

```
var navigationItemsWidth = 0;
$('.navigation-bar .nav li').each(function(){
    navigationItemsWidth += $(this).width();
});
```

If you want to reuse it, use this :

```
$.fn.totalWidth = function(){
    var navigationItemsWidth = 0;
    this.each(function(){
        navigationItemsWidth += $(this).width();
    });    
    return navigationItemsWidth;
}

var navigationItemsWidth = $('navigation-bar .nav li').totalWidth()
```

Answer (score 3):

One way in a lot :

```
$sum = 0;

$('.navigation-bar .nav li').each(function(){
   $sum = $sum + $(this).width();
});

alert($sum);
```

Comment: Just a style note, but aren't variables usually $-prefixed for jQuery objects to make them stand out? (not for non-jQuery variables)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You teach me something, do you have a link about it ?

Comment: @TheLittlePig I don't think there is a *"link"*, it is just a good practice since Javascript has no variable type. As for me, i also like to declar my variable prefixed with the type : arrName, strName, objName, intName and etc...

Comment: Ok... So thanks to you two, as I said you teach me something ;-)

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon: Hungarian notation and its variants (i.e. prefixing variable names with its type) are sooooo last century :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var navigationItemsWidth = (function(){
  var total = 0;
  $('.navigation-bar .nav li').each(function() { total+=$(this).width();});
  return total;
})();
```

Or if you want to reuse that function you can extract it out rather than executing it straight away, or add it as a jQuery plugin

```
$.fn.totalWidth = function() {
 var total = 0;
 this.each(function() { total+=$(this).width();});
  return total;
};

var navigationItemsWidth = $('.navigation-bar .nav li').totalWidth();
```

Comment: Q: What was your intention wrapping the code in an immediate function?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I wanted to wrap it in a function so `total` wasn't available outside of it. Then I executed the function like that so the name `navigationItemsWidth` made sense and didn't want to declare a `totalWidth` function. And for some reason I thought it better to create such a function in another answer and not an edit -- seems like a bad idea since the highest answer made the exact edit at the same time. So have deleted my other answer and moved it in here *sigh*

Comment: Ok, that makes sense in theory, however that first code just substitutes one new variable (navigationItemsWidth) for another (total) so scoping `total` makes less sense that just using `navigationItemsWidth` :) +1 for the plugin version anyway as I saw you authored it at the same time as the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
var count = $('.navigation-bar .nav li').size();
var list_items_width=array();
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     list_items_width.push($('.navigation-bar .nav li').eq(i).width());
}
var total_width = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    total_width = total_width + list_items_width[j];
}
```

Comment: -1: Creating and iterating a temporary array, for the simple summing up of widths, is very wasteful of code-size, run-time speed and memory usage. please see any of the up-voted answers for better solutions to this problem.

Comment: yeah, you 're right. Just had this code snippets because I'm working on something where I need the array. Just tried to help... but sure - it's not the best solution

Comment: Yes, sorry to be harsh. All it needs now is an image carousel to finish it :)